# Conditional probability with two conditions

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am trying to solve this conditional and joint probability quiz. I am not able to answer one question. Can anyone help? I am trying to understand how any of the answer can be correct, because none of my calculation is leading to these answers.

The question is:

Consider a set containing all Science students OR all male students. What is the Probability that a randomly selected person will belong to this set?

[image]

The answers provided are:

- 40/90
- 50/90
- 310/500
- 260/500

I am not sure which formula to use for finding out this answer. Any help is appreciated.
P.S - I also asked in stats group but I am not getting any answers so posting in math group as well hoping some math wiz can help me :)

---

|  | Science | Others | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Male** | 80 | 180 | 260 |
| **Female** | 70 | 170 | 240 |
| **Total** | **150** | **350** | **500** |

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.
Please use Markdown to typeset tables: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer results to me

$$\frac{150+260-80}{500}=\frac{330}{500}$$

Thus none of the provided answers

Comment: Thank you for your answer @tommik. I thought so too...I had arrived at 330/500, but since I did not see it in the answers I thought something was wrong with my calculation

Comment: @PKTN100 :  I edited you answer including an example of table that you can use instead of inserting a picture. I hope this can help.

Comment: Does this explanation make sense to you? -

This question deals with a probability concept called the ‘OR’. There is a formula for OR, which is — P(A OR B) = P(A) + P(B) – P(A AND B)

In this example, you’re looking at two things: Sc and Male.

So, the question asked is —P(Sc OR Male) = P(Sc) + P(Male) – P(Sc AND Male)

Using the table in the question description, you see that —P(Sc) = 90/500

 

P(Male) = 260/500


P(Sc AND Male) = 40/500

Therefore

P(Sc OR Male) = P(Sc) + P( Male) – P(Sc AND Male)

= 90/500 + 260/500 – 40/500 = (90 + 260 – 40)/500 = 310/500

Comment: This is the explanation I got in the site.

Comment: @PKTN100 : yes, makes sense! but the question was "Science OR Male" thus it is $(150+260-80)/500$. Perhaps it is only a typo in the exercise...if you want "English OR Male" it is correctly $310/500$

Comment: I dont get how they arrived upon 90/500... Can you give some insight? Nobody else seems to help :(

Comment: @PKTN100 it's a typo in the exercise. $P(Sc)=150/500$ while $P(Eng)=90/500$

Comment: Aha! I see now! Thank you so much, @tommik, your help is much appreciated!